# Customise Highstock tooltip conditionally

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

I would like to make tooltip in Highstock styled differently(not just style of content, but style for tooltip itself. For example, different padding, shadow, border radious etc) when hovering over flag series and line serieses. However, it looks like these properties needs to be configured in the tooltip configuration object. Not sure if it can be dynamically changed.

Like in this jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/cixowuloxa/1/edit?js,output

What's the better way to give 'Summer arrives' tooltip different style than other shared tooltips?

Comment: Would mouseOver and mouseOut events be helpful in this case? See the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/

Comment: @NavjotSingh do you mean adding a tooltip dynamically in mouseOver callback? I think that will also require you to get the position of the cursor and put the div to corresponding position?

Comment: Yes. One way to go about it would be to find the position of the 'Summer' div element and display a custom div element beside it.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. In the formatter callback wrap the text in the html tags and style it using css, inline or by class name, depending if it is a flag or line series. Make sure you set `useHTML` to true.

```
 tooltip: {
        useHTML:true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        headerFormat: '',
        shared: true,
        formatter: function(){
          if (!!this.points) {
            return this.points
           .reduce(
           function(prev, cur) { 
             return prev +
               '<br>' + cur.series.name + ': '+ cur.y;
           }, '');
          } 
          return "<div style='border:5px solid black; padding: 20px'>Summer arrives!</div>"; 
        },
        padding: 0
      }
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/hpeq7Lbe/1/

Actually, you can set different options for flag's and line's tooltip, but not all the options are supported, e.g. padding or border width will not work - they have to be set in the tooltip's global options.

```
plotOptions: {
        line: {
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'line',
          borderWidth: 10, // not supported
          padding: 10 // not supported
        }
      },
      flags: {
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'flags',
          borderWidth: 1, //not supported
          padding: 1 // not supported
        }
      }
    }
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/hpeq7Lbe/3/